# Need the height of an invalidated Swing component

Tags: swing, jsplitpane, java

The basic setup is this:  I have a vertical JSplitPane that I want to have a fixed-size bottom component and a resizing top component, which I accomplished by calling `setResizeWeight(1.0)`.  In this application there is a button to restore the "default" window configuration.  The default height of the window is the desktop height, and the default divider location is 100 pixels from the bottom of the split pane.

To set the divider location to 100px, I take the JSplitPane height - 100.  The problem is, just before this I resize the JFrame, and since the code is in a button callback, the JSplitPane has been invalidated but not yet resized.  So the divider location is set incorrectly.

Here is a SSCCE.  Click the button twice to see the problem.  The first click will resize the window, but the divider location remains the same (relative to the bottom of the window).  The second click properly moves the divider, since the window size didn't change.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SSCCE {

    /**
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SSCCE();
    }

    private final JFrame f = new JFrame("JSplitPane SSCE");
    private final JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,true);

    public SSCCE() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sp.add(new JLabel("top"));
        sp.add(new JLabel("bottom"));
        sp.setResizeWeight(1.0);

        f.getContentPane().add(sp);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Resize to Default") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                restoreDefaults();
            }
        }),BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        f.setSize(400,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void restoreDefaults() {
        f.setSize(f.getWidth(), getDesktopRect(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()).height);
        sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);  // Does not work on first button press
    }

    Rectangle getDesktopRect(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        Insets insets = toolkit.getScreenInsets(gc);
        return new Rectangle(insets.left, insets.top, size.width - (insets.left + insets.right), size.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom));
    }

}
```

I have thought of a few ways I might get around this, but they all seem sort of hackish.  So far the best idea I've had has been to call `f.validate()` in between setting the frame size and setting the divider location, but I'm concerned there might be side effects to forcing validation early.

The other option I thought of is to use `EventQueue.invokeLater()` to put the call to set the divider location at the end of the event queue.  But that seems risky to me - I'm assuming the JSplitPane will have been validated at that point, and I'm concerned that may be a faulty assumption to make.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `System.out.println(sp.getLastDividerLocation());` returns -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took a while (probably due to being early morning here :-) to understand the problem, so just to make sure I got it:

- the size of the bottom component can be whatever the user decides at all times
- when resizing the frame all height change should happen to the top component
- there's an option to restore to default sizes, independent of any setting before
- "default" means the bottom component must have a fixed height of xx

If so, the solution is to separate the frame resizing from the sizing the bottom component. Your second option is dead on: resize the frame and wrap the bottom comp resize into a invokeLater (EventQueue or SwingUtilities, doesn't matter).

```
void restoreDefaults() {
    f.setSize(f.getWidth(), getDesktopRect(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()).height);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);  

        }
    });
}
```

That's guaranteed to work as expected, because the invokeLater puts the request as last after all already queued events:

```
 /**
 * Causes <i>doRun.run()</i> to be executed asynchronously on the
 * AWT event dispatching thread.  This will happen after all
 * pending AWT events have been processed.  [...]
 * If invokeLater is called from the event dispatching thread --
 * for example, from a JButton's ActionListener -- the <i>doRun.run()</i> will
 * still be deferred until all pending events have been processed.
```

Comment: +1 looks like a very simple, clean and understandable approach - and without flags :-)

Comment: @david yeah, flags are evil :-)

Answer (score 2):

nothing complicated, basic Swing Rules

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE {

    /**
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SSCCE sSCCE = new SSCCE();
            }
        });
    }
    private final JFrame f = new JFrame("JSplitPane SSCE");
    private final JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, 
           true);

    public SSCCE() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sp.add(new JLabel("top"));
        sp.add(new JLabel("bottom"));
        sp.setResizeWeight(1.0);
        f.getContentPane().add(sp);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction(
          "Resize to Default") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(sp.getLastDividerLocation());
                restoreDefaults();
            }
        }), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void restoreDefaults() {
    //EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    //    @Override
    //    public void run() {
            f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(f.getWidth(), 
                getDesktopRect(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()).height));
            f.pack();
            sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);  
                // Does not work on first button press                
    //    }
    //});
    }

    Rectangle getDesktopRect(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        Insets insets = toolkit.getScreenInsets(gc);
        return new Rectangle(insets.left, insets.top, 
             size.width - (insets.left + insets.right), 
             size.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine, but I'm confused as to the difference...why is the JSplitPane laid out immediately following the frame resize in your example and not in the original?  The button action is also on the event queue (I think), so what difference does it make wrapping it in `invokeLater`?

Comment: actually found it will still fails if you change it to `f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 120));` (depending on your toolkit you might have to play with the number a little, important point is the initial height of the scroll pane should be < 100px

Comment: yes you are right (about EDT), but  'System.out.println(sp.getLastDividerLocation());' returns -1 and that was really wrong value, but looks like as events for resize JSplitPane, ends before wrong f.setSize, heavens there must be setPreferredSize() and pack(), my mistake, that my bad too, I'll amend my post, there no needed delayed action in EDT

Comment: pack() calls validate()...its similar to what I was considering, but I think pack() may be better than validate() in this case.  Seems promising...I want to give some time though to see if anyone can top it...

Comment: oh and I think I understand about the EDT now, I forgot to mention to assume `restoreDefaults()` is only called from the button listener.  In general I think the way you did it is safer.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom action class that handles the button click and the resize event. This approach would look like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SSCCE {

    /**
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SSCCE();
    }

    private final JFrame f = new JFrame("JSplitPane SSCE");
    private final JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,true);

    public SSCCE() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sp.add(new JLabel("top"));
        sp.add(new JLabel("bottom"));
        sp.setResizeWeight(1.0);

        f.getContentPane().add(sp);

        CustomListener resizeViaButtonListener = new CustomListener("Resize to Default");

        f.getContentPane().add(new JButton(resizeViaButtonListener), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        f.addComponentListener(resizeViaButtonListener);

        f.setSize(400,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void restoreDefaults() {
        f.setSize(f.getWidth(), getDesktopRect(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()).height);
        sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);  // Does not work on first button press
    }

    Rectangle getDesktopRect(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        Insets insets = toolkit.getScreenInsets(gc);
        return new Rectangle(insets.left, insets.top, size.width - (insets.left + insets.right), size.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom));
    }

    class CustomListener extends AbstractAction implements ComponentListener {

        CustomListener(String actionDescription) {
            super(actionDescription);
        }

        private boolean resizedViaButtonClick = false;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            resizedViaButtonClick = true;
            f.setSize(f.getWidth(), getDesktopRect(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()).height);
            sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);
            // you need this also here because if the component is not resized when clicking the button
            // it is possible that the divider location must be changed. This happens when the user clicks
            // the button after changing the divider but not resizing the frame.
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if ( resizedViaButtonClick ) {
                resizedViaButtonClick = false;
                sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) { /* do nothing */ }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { /* do nothing */ }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { /* do nothing */ }

    }

}
```

This way the code that is responsible for handling the logical task of setting the standard size will be in one single and easy to understand class.

Comment: interesting approach...I can't find any obvious holes.  The production code is more complicated than the SSCCE, and I'm not sure if I can easily wedge a custom listener in there like that, but it is a solution

Comment: One downside may be the flag that indicates that the resize event was fired by the button click. Having a flag for this just feels kinda wrong. :-)

Comment: yeah, the flag does bother me a little...though heaven knows I've abused flags for much worse ;)  I suppose if for whatever reason I was setting the frame size twice to different sizes within the button action, it might break...though I can't see how/why I would do that in either the SSCCE or the production code

Answer (score 2):

> but I think pack() may be better than validate()

I generally try to avoid invoking setPreferredSize() on any component. I would rather let the layout manager do its job. In this case this would mean setting the size of the frame and let the BorderLayout take all the available space.

```
    void restoreDefaults() {
//        f.setSize(f.getWidth(), getDesktopRect(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()).height);
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
        f.setSize(f.getWidth(), bounds.height);
        f.validate();
        sp.setDividerLocation(sp.getSize().height - 100);  // Does not work on first button press
    }
```