# Swing component setSize()/setBounds() issue

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel

### Contents

---

1. Overview
2. Example Code
3. Screenshots of Problem

---

### 1. Overview of problem

---

So I'm writing a GUI for a complicated program I'm developing, and I get tired of trying to get components to scale correctly when the window is resized.

At first I was using several layouts inside the jframe, and each jpanel to try and place the components correctly and scale them appropriately. Naturally, I got fed up with them, and I started trying to scale and set the x,y positions of the components dynamically (it's so much easier :D).

Basically I'm trying to divide the screen into three sections left margin (JSplitPane), center (JTabbedPane), and right margin (JSplitPane). I don't think the internal components matter at this point. **The main problem is** the right JSplitPane scales over the whole window despite my using setBounds() to place the x,y over on the right and set the size to 21% of the total width. It seems to interact weird with the other panels.

---

### 2. Example Code

---

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class test extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

/* Constants =========================================================================*/
    private         final   double      LEFT_SIZE           =   .21;
    private         final   double      CENTER_SIZE         =   .58;
    private         final   double      RIGHT_SIZE          =   .21;
    private         final   int         TOP_PADDING         =   50;
    private         final   int         LEFT_PADDING        =   4;
    private         final   int         RIGHT_PADDING       =   4;
    private         final   int         BOTTOM_PADDING      =   4;
    private         final   int         MIN_WIDTH           =   640;
    private         final   int         MIN_HEIGHT          =   480;

    public  static  final   String      INIT_TITLE          =   "TestFrame v0.01";
/* End Constants =====================================================================*/

/* Instance Variables ================================================================*/
    private                 int         contentWidth;
    private                 int         contentHeight;
/* End Instance Variables ============================================================*/

/* Objects ===========================================================================*/        
    public  static  test        window;     

    /* Begin Frame Design =========================================================== */
        private         JSplitPane      left;
        private         JButton           button1;  private     JButton     button2;            
        private         JTabbedPane     center;
        private         JPanel            panel1;       private     JPanel      panel2;         
        private         JSplitPane      right;
        private         JButton           button3;  private     JButton     button4;
    /* End Frame Design ============================================================= */

/* End Objects ====================================================================== */

/** Initializes and Places all GUI elements **/
public test ( String windowName ) {
    super(windowName);              //call parent constructor
    this.addWindowListener(this);   //adds window event functionality such as close

    this.setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //Starts program maximized
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(MIN_WIDTH,MIN_HEIGHT));
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setMaximumSize(this.getSize());        

    /* Begin Init JFrame this ------------------------------------------------------------ */       
            button1 = new JButton("button1");               
            button2 = new JButton("button2");               
        left = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, button1, button2);
        left.setResizeWeight(1);

            button3 = new JButton("button3");               
            button4 = new JButton("button4");               
        right = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, button3, button4);
        right.setResizeWeight(.25);

            panel1 = new JPanel();              
            panel2 = new JPanel();              
        center = new JTabbedPane();
        center.addTab("Panel1", panel1);
        center.addTab("Panel2", panel2);

        this.add(left);
        this.add(center);
        this.add(right);

        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized    (ComponentEvent e) {
                window.contentWidth = window.getWidth() - window.LEFT_PADDING - window.RIGHT_PADDING;
                window.contentHeight = window.getHeight() - window.TOP_PADDING - window.BOTTOM_PADDING;

                window.left.setBounds               (   0,                                                  0,  (int)(window.contentWidth * window.LEFT_SIZE),      window.contentHeight);
                window.center.setBounds             (   window.left.getWidth(),                             0,  (int)(window.contentWidth * window.CENTER_SIZE),    window.contentHeight);
                window.panel1.setBounds             (   0,                                                  0,  (int)(window.contentWidth * window.CENTER_SIZE),    window.contentHeight);
                window.panel2.setBounds             (   0,                                                  0,  (int)(window.contentWidth * window.CENTER_SIZE),    window.contentHeight);
                window.right.setBounds              (   window.left.getWidth() + window.center.getWidth(),  0,  (int)(window.contentWidth * window.RIGHT_SIZE),     window.contentHeight);
             }
            public void componentHidden     (ComponentEvent e) {}
            public void componentMoved      (ComponentEvent e) {}
            public void componentShown      (ComponentEvent e) {}    

        });
        /* End Init JFrame this -------------------------------------------------------------- */
}

// window event abstracts
@Override
public void windowClosing       (WindowEvent event)     { window.dispose(); System.exit(0); } 
public void windowClosed        (WindowEvent event)     {}
public void windowDeiconified   (WindowEvent event)     {} 
public void windowIconified     (WindowEvent event)     {} 
public void windowActivated     (WindowEvent event)     {} 
public void windowDeactivated   (WindowEvent event)     {} 
public void windowOpened        (WindowEvent event)     {}

public static void main(String[] args){     
    window = new test(INIT_TITLE); 
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

---

### 3. Screenshots

---

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: *"You can find a runnable example here with jarfile included."*  No thanks.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"set the x,y positions of the components dynamically (it's so much easier :D)."*  Your troubles seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is a SSCCE. The runnable example contains only a few more lines of code that set up the frame and calculate some padding elements. This is the bulk of the code you need.

Comment: @Kronos25 `bulk of the code you need` maybe interesting informations for you most of us don't needed something, nor your last comment :-)

Comment: @Kronos25  *"This is a SSCCE. The runnable example contains only a few more lines of code"*  An SSCCE does not need ***anything else***.  There are no prizes for 'close'.  Note for future - you are talking to the author of the SSCCE document.

Comment: @mKorbel I'm unsure what you mean by that comment, can you please clarify? :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I will look at it again and see what I can remove. :/ do you have any suggestions? Perhaps some people would like to be able to run the program and see the behavior in action?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Made example code as short as possible while still being compilable and semi-nice looking. I supposed I can now remove the jar and source line by your standards?

Comment: *"Perhaps some people would like to be able to run the program and see the behavior in action?"*  Umm.. yes, an SSCCE is supposed to be runnable.  Have you actually *read* the SSCCE document?  As far as I am concerned, an SSCCE can be 150 lines of code and if it is 'SC, C & an E', it is 'short' enough.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's under 150 lines. about 100. No I haven't read SSCCE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson edited, no moar jar source. This is runnable. Shows the problem with scaling the right most element. The left and center elements both scale fine.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think the internal components matter at this point.

As discussed in [*Should I avoid the use of set[Preferred|Maximum|Minimum]Size methods in Java Swing?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), nothing could be further from the truth. Correct use of layouts *relies* on a component's preferred size. That size is carefully calculated based on the contents. Second guessing, as shown in your example, is doomed to fail.

Instead, add components and `pack()` the frame. In the example below, the center panel returns an arbitrary result to show how `pack()` does its work.

Addendum: Two additional points helpfully adduced by @mKorbel:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625843/230513) that shows how to use `setDividerLocation()` in `invokeLater()`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static final String INIT_TITLE = "TestFrame v0.02";
    public static Test window;
    private JSplitPane left;
    private JTabbedPane center;
    private JSplitPane right;

    public Test(String windowName) {
        super(windowName);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        left = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
            new JButton("button1"), new JButton("button2"));
        left.setResizeWeight(0.5);

        right = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
            new JButton("button3"), new JButton("button4"));
        right.setResizeWeight(0.5);

        center = new JTabbedPane();
        center.addTab("Panel1", new MyPanel());
        center.addTab("Panel2", new MyPanel());

        this.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private Dimension d = new Dimension(320, 240);

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return d;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                window = new Test(INIT_TITLE);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel: Thanks! Sorry, I overlooked your other useful points; ping me if you restore your answer.

Comment: I didn't want to have to use these stupid layouts, but it appears there isn't another way :(

Comment: @trashgod no I don't want to restore my deleted post here, btw very nice thread, isn't it,

Comment: @Kronos25: Kudos for moving toward [acceptance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance). I can only assure you that _not_ using layouts is _much_ worse.