# Inconsistent JFrame layout

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have a JFrame which displays two JSplitPanes (one inside the other).

> For some reason the divider location is inconsistent.

What I mean by that is that sometimes its displayed on the correct position where I have set it, while other times it doesn't. When the position is wrong, its wrong for both split panels. Here is the code I am using for the JSplitPanes:

```
        JPanel javaPanel = core.getComponentPanel(2);
        JSplitPane splitA = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                javaPanel.getComponent(0), javaPanel.getComponent(1));
        double pos = (screenDim.getHeight() * 72) / 100;
        splitA.setDividerLocation((int) pos);
        JSplitPane mainSplitP = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                new JScrollPane(getCoreComponents()), splitA);
        return mainSplitP;
```

On the JFrame I have a JPanel with CardLayout. To add the mainSplitP I use the following method:

```
    private void setFrameContent(Container content, String title) {
        appContent.add(content, title);
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (appContent.getLayout());
        cl.show(appContent, title);
        appFrame.pack();
    }
```

What could be causing this inconsistency ?

Comment: I think the layout manager you are using has something to do with your issue.

Comment: Layout is CardLayout. And shouldn't I always get the same result?

Comment: TRy to surround divider location set in SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: And note that Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `JComponents` knows own size after `pack()`, or when they're once time visible on the screen
- wrap [JSplitPane's setDividerLocation to the invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625843/714968)

Comment: Had to add some ugly code with casting but at least it works. Thanks !

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way to have the divider location based on the preferred size of the components the JSplitPane contains ? That way since my components got a set preferred size I might not need to set the location manually ?